# Increase readability in this try-catch?

Tags: c#, optimization, code-readability

I was wondering if there is a more aesthetic/easier to read way to write the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{ 
    // If m.GetString(i) throws an exception, continue.
    // Otherwise, do stuff.       
    try
    {
        string s = m.GetString(i);
        continue;
    }           
    catch (InvalidCastException) 
    { 
    }

    // do stuff with the message that you know is not a string.
}
```

Here's what m looks like:

```
msg[0] = 10
msg[1] = "string"
msg[2] = 2.224574743
// Etc.
// Assume it's different every time.
```

So therefore when I do `m.GetString(0)` in this example, it throws an exception, as `msg[0]` is a `uint` and not a `string`. This is what I use to get the type, since `m` does not contain a GetType and I cannot edit m.

m is an instance of class `Message` in a library that I cannot edit.

However, despite this working just fine, it feels inefficient (and certainly not reader-friendly) to intentionally create exceptions, even if it's in a `try-catch`, in order to get the type.

Is there a better way or am I stuck with this?

**Edit:** Alright, I researched the `Message` class some more (which I should have done to begin with, my apologies). It is an `IEnumerable<object>`

Comment: IF you can avoid the exception, you should.. Exceptions add overhead

Comment: You should find out what type of exception m.GetString() throws (assuming you can't access the code behind it and handle it without an exception) then only catch that type of exception. Catching every exception possible and just continuing isn't good

Comment: What is the type of `m`?

Comment: Can you not modify GetString to avoid throwing an exception and returning a null in case it's not a string and null strings are excluded or a boolean indicating whether the value is a string + an out parameter to return that string

Comment: Like Matthew said, what is m? You could always put the item in an object variable and then do a gettype.

Comment: m is an `IEnumerable<object>`

Comment: @TakoM. If it's an `IEnumerable<object>` then it won't have methods for `GetString` or an indexer.  It may implement that interface, but the variable itself is actually defined as some more derived type with additional functionality.  What's that more derived type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that I know that `m` is an `IEnumerable<object>`, I think this is probably your best bet:

```
foreach (string s in m.OfType<string>())
{
    // Process s, which can't be null.
}
```

Nice and simple and it appears to handle all the logic that you want, i.e. it will process only the items in the sequence that are strings, and it will ignore all objects of other types.

However as Servy points out, this will not handle nulls in the list because `null` does not have any type at all.

---

[My previous answer before I knew the type of `m`]

I think you can take one of three approaches to this:

(1) Add a `bool TryGetString(int index, out string)` method to whatever type `m` is in your example and then do

```
if (m.TryGetString(i, out s)) 
    // Process s (need to check for null!)
```

(2) Add a `bool IsString(int index)` method and call that before calling `GetString()`.

```
if (m.IsString(i)) 
{
    s = m.GetString(i); 
    // Process s (need to check for null!)
```

(3) Alternatively, you could expose the item via something like `GetObject(int index)` and then do something like Iiya suggested:

```
 string s = m.GetObject(i) as string; 

 if (s != null) 
     // Process s
```

I think (1) or (3) would be best, although there might be a much better solution that we could suggest if we had more information about `m`.

Comment: Yes, m is an IEnumerable<object>. I will try your fourth option out now.

Comment: Note that if you have any `null` objects that *should* represent strings that could be a problem; without knowing your data and how you're expecting to use it we can't know if it's appropriate or not.

Comment: Yes Servy has a good point. If an item in a list of objects is null, it cannot have any type (since there is no object to have any type, of course!)

Comment: @TakoM. Sorry I had edited away my old answer; but since you referenced it I've reinstated it now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to process only strings in a non-strongly typed sequence of data, use next code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{ 
    string s = m[i] as string;

    if(s != null)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this still allow non-strings since there are types that will cast to a string successfully?

Comment: @emd `string` is sealed, so it cannot have an subtypes, as such there aren't any types besides `string` that can be cast to a string.